# Parse bad html file in Ansible as xml

Tags: html, xml, ansible

I have a response from Confluence with some info. I am replacing specific keys in the JSON response and then doing a PUT request so I can update a page.
The problem is, I cannot parse the file correctly(by keys) because it is not a valid file (it seems).
From the whole response, I need to replace only 1 value:

```
 {
    "cache_control": "no-store",
    "changed": false,
    "connection": "close",
    "content": "{\"id\":\"164794022\",\"type\":\"page\",\"status\":\"current\",\"title\":\"Jira Dev\",\"body\":{\"storage\":{\"value\":\"<p class=\\\"auto-cursor-target\\\"><br /></p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\\\"details\\\" ac:schema-version=\\\"1\\\" ac:macro-id=\\\"6f61e6bd-3edc-4e93-a9b7-2f15cd5fc33c\\\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"id\\\">1</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body><p class=\\\"auto-cursor-target\\\"><br /></p><table class=\\\"wrapped\\\"><colgroup><col /><col /></colgroup><tbody><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\">Hostname</th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\">jira-dev</td></tr><tr><th>IP</th><td>192.168.182.231</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\">Static/Dynamic IP?</th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\"><div class=\\\"content-wrapper\\\"><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\\\"status\\\" ac:schema-version=\\\"1\\\" ac:macro-id=\\\"3a801df2-b1e5-4209-88dd-06483f6e368a\\\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"colour\\\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"title\\\">Static</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p></div></td></tr><tr><th>Server</th><td>Hosted by IT Team</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\"><p>Installed Product</p></th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\">Jira Software + Service Management</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\"><p>Necessity</p></th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\"><div class=\\\"content-wrapper\\\"><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\\\"status\\\" ac:schema-version=\\\"1\\\" ac:macro-id=\\\"9e5e9eba-4648-4599-a052-865aaa3535f7\\\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"colour\\\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"title\\\">Normal</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p></div></td></tr><tr><th>OS</th><td>Ubuntu 20.04</td></tr><tr><th>Monitoring</th><td>No</td></tr><tr><th>Backup</th><td>No</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\">Installed Product URL</th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\"><a href=\\\"http://jira-dev:8080\\\">http://jira-dev:8080</a></td></tr><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\">Using SSO</th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\">No</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\">Product credentials</th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\"><div class=\\\"content-wrapper\\\"><p class=\\\"auto-cursor-target\\\"><br /></p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\\\"secure\\\" ac:schema-version=\\\"1\\\" ac:macro-id=\\\"baba2872-b3b8-45e2-a5b4-fe7384f862d2\\\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"title\\\">Product credentials</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body><span class=\\\"sec-icon-lock icon16\\\">&nbsp;</span><pre class=\\\"secret\\\">-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\\nVersion: BCPG v1.59\\n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\\nK4kT09FF/Wcc3j6f4pSwR1B23p9fNE17iUvcNoU9c+tD3g==\\n=Qwvl\\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\\n</pre>Secured content</ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p class=\\\"auto-cursor-target\\\"><br /></p></div></td></tr><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\">Host credentials</th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\"><div class=\\\"content-wrapper\\\"><p class=\\\"auto-cursor-target\\\"><br /></p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\\\"secure\\\" ac:schema-version=\\\"1\\\" ac:macro-id=\\\"fbc7388c-0965-4b10-8acc-0d1233ca3ef4\\\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"title\\\">Host credentials</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body><span class=\\\"sec-icon-lock icon16\\\">&nbsp;</span><pre class=\\\"secret\\\">-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\\nVersion: OpenPGP.js v4.10.10\\nComment: https://openpgpjs.org\\n\\nwcBMAxOSOe32i2V3Agf+IKFt2bSmyFl4Sk3YtTf1cXu+Xv9yZ0c/iP4RJ9ll\\n5P9LM8DKPtBL+othBMLEUigNEgjXOrANp11W/endk1Ulst4UkTyttQQx5JZ2\\nyNI2Q0M5uUfj/2tlCq9TTO1eXb/bffM+cKzk0D68UWC+EBvXpRp5sbKVz1Ya\\nJj7nYItETTuWPUjF0uEaYVlbmsdfe3dvVy63EPw5GZdVobwv++93ZIEEhKmS\\nvc+d+iw9L+Ov16kXCQaHNXzyiwtvp5nIIMYORp3IaRrbzmBqiV07RjIZrvNR\\nyozEGcNWdSW7egC1k+JEF+qi2kLASglKLWFWmHn/cMpetULl8Z9c3VFZpnu7\\nENLBVwFQ2f3uaF+A6t19Zi5CKptV+f1qtYekyZZok61TBkldQD4AL2UEBDB0\\nMpUfEEdy4vgYqNjGWGOpX2QbWjXZDhxPAQgNr6XxxcJ7L1gzHLZT45MjFzB9\\nBBhtX/qvczL1uWNHwYErUZGbwX6pwfyfbTUDX57bDbOYUG0A+nZjWIRJt5tA\\nFPWiM0vicufuMACUYG00n3+C2Eu/DPIcRaHRhnz1aEDOQ4dX19ZpUCY0hWeZ\\ndnhtLEYOXxTy6bgsHoBIHxac+DQ9a/0iFSNIErXfIq7yrABPEfn04Kc3tkXJ\\nK+RAFQ7aJ93LjkfYMqxjLVp1lAZ05dealMLHStkvisPI3Y0qDGwPKmg9kkMD\\nBnF5OuU6L/RXzei9eUHU4O2HOJtf5ClTZ7vHBXyBzoZ1JOUu2axAaOJq7Y8h\\nm7L1vYJngepSMrh4xLzQXuoegM049NNSIsumioCyF4VBvtopATta1cG/U2dF\\n/lahHpm0l3FtdWodNCag2Ejsr61+H5gIHinqPZC96MUmdbOOzWnHXlXjAAO/\\nzkXNDAAJss+WolNuF+o8yUd9w9woYIuqzrXOOMhEM1pAxAiBhOjeXI3lQXa6\\nf0pr/txZXy+qrvuQlcaF5EyWc4GrLTnuceBWAhHIrsaEhLQVf5RtJDrvgdyR\\nJLw4+79Hzt+/R6gRP6Pat1bN9e734/w09gpdvnolzWxTzpn7Wuje4uX4w+M=\\n=CiIl\\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\\n</pre>Secured content</ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p class=\\\"auto-cursor-target\\\"><br /></p></div></td></tr><tr><th colspan=\\\"1\\\">Status</th><td colspan=\\\"1\\\"><div class=\\\"content-wrapper\\\"><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\\\"status\\\" ac:schema-version=\\\"1\\\" ac:macro-id=\\\"43f14423-450c-483b-9dd6-ef711982db40\\\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"colour\\\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"title\\\">PING</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><span> </span><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\\\"status\\\" ac:schema-version=\\\"1\\\" ac:macro-id=\\\"1e1a2aa2-80ee-49e9-8f4c-5c5335ac3f52\\\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"colour\\\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"title\\\">ssh</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><span> </span><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\\\"status\\\" ac:schema-version=\\\"1\\\" ac:macro-id=\\\"68710b0e-2f40-4156-ac81-15f1c3c1d025\\\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"colour\\\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\\\"title\\\">HTTP</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p></div></td></tr></tbody></table><p class=\\\"auto-cursor-target\\\"><br /></p></ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p>\",\"representation\":\"storage\",\"_expandable\":{\"content\":\"/rest/api/content/164794022\"}},\"_expandable\":{\"editor\":\"\",\"view\":\"\",\"export_view\":\"\",\"styled_view\":\"\",\"anonymous_export_view\":\"\"}},\"extensions\":{\"position\":\"none\"},\"_links\":{\"webui\":\"/display/AT/Jira+Dev\",\"edit\":\"/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=164794022&draftShareId=e44b5ec9-f1a1-463e-aa40-6667c6022ec8\",\"tinyui\":\"/x/po7SCQ\",\"collection\":\"/rest/api/content\",\"base\":\"https://blabla/confluence\",\"context\":\"/confluence\",\"self\":\"https://blabla/confluence/rest/api/content/164794022\"},\"_expandable\":{\"container\":\"/rest/api/space/AT\",\"metadata\":\"\",\"operations\":\"\",\"children\":\"/rest/api/content/164794022/child\",\"restrictions\":\"/rest/api/content/164794022/restriction/byOperation\",\"history\":\"/rest/api/content/164794022/history\",\"ancestors\":\"\",\"version\":\"\",\"descendants\":\"/rest/api/content/164794022/descendant\",\"space\":\"/rest/api/space/AT\"}}",
    "content_type": "application/json",
    "date": "Fri, 10 Sep 2021 12:11:19 GMT",
    "elapsed": 0,
    "expires": "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT",
    "failed": false,
    "json": {
        "_expandable": {
            "ancestors": "",
            "children": "/rest/api/content/164794022/child",
            "container": "/rest/api/space/AT",
            "descendants": "/rest/api/content/164794022/descendant",
            "history": "/rest/api/content/164794022/history",
            "metadata": "",
            "operations": "",
            "restrictions": "/rest/api/content/164794022/restriction/byOperation",
            "space": "/rest/api/space/AT",
            "version": ""
        },
        "_links": {
            "base": "https://blabla/confluence",
            "collection": "/rest/api/content",
            "context": "/confluence",
            "edit": "/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=164794022&draftShareId=e44b5ec9-f1a1-463e-aa40-6667c6022ec8",
            "self": "https://blabla/confluence/rest/api/content/164794022",
            "tinyui": "/x/po7SCQ",
            "webui": "/display/AT/Jira+Dev"
        },
        "body": {
            "_expandable": {
                "anonymous_export_view": "",
                "editor": "",
                "export_view": "",
                "styled_view": "",
                "view": ""
            },
            "storage": {
                "_expandable": {
                    "content": "/rest/api/content/164794022"
                },
                "representation": "storage",
                "value": "<p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"details\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"6f61e6bd-3edc-4e93-a9b7-2f15cd5fc33c\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"id\">1</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p><table class=\"wrapped\"><colgroup><col /><col /></colgroup><tbody><tr><th colspan=\"1\">Hostname</th><td colspan=\"1\">jira-dev</td></tr><tr><th>IP</th><td>192.168.182.231</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\"1\">Static/Dynamic IP?</th><td colspan=\"1\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"3a801df2-b1e5-4209-88dd-06483f6e368a\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">Static</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p></div></td></tr><tr><th>Server</th><td>Hosted by IT Team</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\"1\"><p>Installed Product</p></th><td colspan=\"1\">Jira Software + Service Management</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\"1\"><p>Necessity</p></th><td colspan=\"1\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"9e5e9eba-4648-4599-a052-865aaa3535f7\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">Normal</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p></div></td></tr><tr><th>OS</th><td>Ubuntu 20.04</td></tr><tr><th>Monitoring</th><td>No</td></tr><tr><th>Backup</th><td>No</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\"1\">Installed Product URL</th><td colspan=\"1\"><a href=\"http://jira-dev:8080\">http://jira-dev:8080</a></td></tr><tr><th colspan=\"1\">Using SSO</th><td colspan=\"1\">No</td></tr><tr><th colspan=\"1\">Product credentials</th><td colspan=\"1\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"secure\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"baba2872-b3b8-45e2-a5b4-fe7384f862d2\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">Product credentials</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body><span class=\"sec-icon-lock icon16\">&nbsp;</span><pre class=\"secret\">-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\nVersion: BCPG v1.59\n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\nK4kT09FF/Wcc3j6f4pSwR1B23p9fNE17iUvcNoU9c+tD3g==\n=Qwvl\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\n</pre>Secured content</ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p></div></td></tr><tr><th colspan=\"1\">Host credentials</th><td colspan=\"1\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"secure\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"fbc7388c-0965-4b10-8acc-0d1233ca3ef4\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">Host credentials</ac:parameter><ac:rich-text-body><span class=\"sec-icon-lock icon16\">&nbsp;</span><pre class=\"secret\">-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----\nVersion: OpenPGP.js v4.10.10\nComment: https://openpgpjs.org\n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\nJLw4+79Hzt+/R6gRP6Pat1bN9e734/w09gpdvnolzWxTzpn7Wuje4uX4w+M=\n=CiIl\n-----END PGP MESSAGE-----\n</pre>Secured content</ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p></div></td></tr><tr><th colspan=\"1\">Status</th><td colspan=\"1\"><div class=\"content-wrapper\"><p><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"43f14423-450c-483b-9dd6-ef711982db40\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">PING</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><span> </span><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"1e1a2aa2-80ee-49e9-8f4c-5c5335ac3f52\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">ssh</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro><span> </span><ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"68710b0e-2f40-4156-ac81-15f1c3c1d025\"><ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter><ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">HTTP</ac:parameter></ac:structured-macro></p></div></td></tr></tbody></table><p class=\"auto-cursor-target\"><br /></p></ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro><p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p><p><br /></p>"
            }
        },
        "extensions": {
            "position": "none"
        },
        "id": "164794022",
        "status": "current",
        "title": "Jira Dev",
        "type": "page"
    },
    "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
    "redirected": false,
    "server": "Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)",
    "set_cookie": "JSESSIONID=5F873F9123B67BA41F1C348D4BB49C92; Path=/confluence; HttpOnly",
    "status": 200,
    "transfer_encoding": "chunked",
    "url": "https://blabla/confluence/rest/api/content/164794022?expand=body.storage",
    "x_ausername": "ansible",
    "x_content_type_options": "nosniff",
    "x_seraph_loginreason": "OK"
}
```

The key i need is :
`json.body.storage.value`

The actual value is an HTML document. I tried parsing it as xml but it is invalid. Also escape characters are in response. They should be there again after edit for the PUT request.
The subset I need to change is inside the value, in a `div`. How can I parse, compare and change the values of `color` depending on `title`. Is there an easy way to parse? Values will be changed only if different from actual values. This is why I need to compare them.

```
<div class=\"content-wrapper\">
                  <p>
                    <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"43f14423-450c-483b-9dd6-ef711982db40\">
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter>
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">PING</ac:parameter>
                    </ac:structured-macro>
                    <span>
                    </span>
                    <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"1e1a2aa2-80ee-49e9-8f4c-5c5335ac3f52\">
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter>
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">ssh</ac:parameter>
                    </ac:structured-macro>
                    <span>
                    </span>
                    <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"68710b0e-2f40-4156-ac81-15f1c3c1d025\">
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Green</ac:parameter>
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">HTTP</ac:parameter>
                    </ac:structured-macro>
                  </p>
                </div>
```

I just need the original page with 3 words edited (again in original `JSON` format). I need the original JSON with

```
<div class=\"content-wrapper\">
                  <p>
                    <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"43f14423-450c-483b-9dd6-ef711982db40\">
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Red</ac:parameter>
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">PING</ac:parameter>
                    </ac:structured-macro>
                    <span>
                    </span>
                    <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"1e1a2aa2-80ee-49e9-8f4c-5c5335ac3f52\">
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Red</ac:parameter>
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">ssh</ac:parameter>
                    </ac:structured-macro>
                    <span>
                    </span>
                    <ac:structured-macro ac:name=\"status\" ac:schema-version=\"1\" ac:macro-id=\"68710b0e-2f40-4156-ac81-15f1c3c1d025\">
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"colour\">Red</ac:parameter>
                      <ac:parameter ac:name=\"title\">HTTP</ac:parameter>
                    </ac:structured-macro>
                  </p>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the JSON as you have it. Reduce it to the relevant keys, but keep it structurally intact, so that it can still be parsed.

Comment: ...also include whatever code you already have, and what precisely you expect as the output/result.

Comment: quickNdirty: `{{ your_html_content_var | replace('>Green<', '>Red<') }}`

Comment: as you see in the original json, they are not the only color properties on the page. They are the last 3. So somehow I have to get only them

Comment: Then use regex_replace with the relevant regex.

Comment: I don't think your bounty can solve the fact that there is not really enough information to answer correctly. Parsing xml requires a valid xml content. Html (unless xhtml) is not valid xml. "bad html" (if this is really the case....) even more invalid. Have you tried using regex_replace ?